# Aggregating MDX Cube Data of Survey results in Tableau

Tags: aggregate, average, mdx, tableau-api, olap-cube

I’m a Tableau developer – but been asked to create a viz from and Cube using MDX (which I have no experience of).

The Cube is connected to Tableau, some Sets have been created for Time dimensions - Current Month etc  – but totally lost trying to aggregate results so I can move on...

The Data I have is a simple survey with 3 questions. The responder (I responder per Form ID) can give 1 of 4 answers to each question – or ignore it.
2 sets have been created in Tableau to reflect these:

Set 1 Questions: Q1, Q2, Q3

Set 2 Answers: No, Maybe, Probably, Yes (and not answered/#NA)

So far, using ad CASE Statement in Tableau Calculated Members, I’ve assigned a value to each of these answers – No = 0, Maybe = 33, Probably = 67, Yes = 100 or #NA.

I’ve created 2 Calculated Members:

[Count of Answers] – so I can show volume of surveys answered:

```
IIF([Answer].[SAnswer].currentmember = [Yes], [Measures].[Number Of 
Answers], (IIF([Answer].[SAnswer].currentmember = [Probably], [Measures]. 
[Number Of Answers], (IIF([Answer].[SAnswer].currentmember = [Maybe], 
[Measures].[Number Of Answers], (IIF([Answer].[SAnswer].currentmember = 
[No], [Measures].[Number Of Answers],0)))))))
```

And,

[Survery Scores]

```
CASE
WHEN [Answer].[SAnswer].currentmember = [Yes] THEN 1.00
WHEN [Answer].[SAnswer].currentmember = [Probably] THEN 0.67
WHEN [Answer].[SAnswer].currentmember = [Maybe] THEN 0.33
WHEN [Answer].[SAnswer].currentmember = [No] THEN 0.00
ELSE NULL
END
```

Where I’m stuck – For each survey form completed, I need the average score:

[Form ID].[001], has 3 questions answered: Q1 = 67%, Q2 =  67%, Q3 = 67% so average is 67%
[Form ID].[002], has 2 questions answered: Q1 = 100%, Q3 = 0% so average is 50%

I’ll need to aggregate these Scored by Country, Region, Job Type, Month hierarchies etc…if I was just using an flat extract I’d use a Nested Include/Fixed LOD…so if the 2 forms above were in the same [June].[USA].[Cleaning] the score would be average of 58.5%.

I'd appreciate a steer on what I need to do to create an aggregated score measure averaging the average score-per-form at any level. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is related more to your Cube design then MDX. The average method that you explained above indicates that the grain of your fact is your form . I would suggest that you edit the design of your fact, by grouping on the fact on formid. Now at what ever data point you query the data the result will be fine.